# How to output difference between two text files?

Tags: python, text, sed, grep, comparison

I'm wondering how I can compare two text files, highlighting the difference between each of them? For example:

File1.txt

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
```

File2.txt

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
```

I'd like to have the following output after comparison of those two files:

```
CCCCC
```

I'm using Python, and tried sed and grep with no luck (I'm interested in linux shell ways of doing this too).

Comment: This question is far more complicated than I think you understand. There are [full commercial packages](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextCompare) aimed at doing this task.

Comment: Hey! What's the point being sarcastic ? I'm not looking for a software doing it ;) I'm a Python beginner so I try to learn as much as I can

Comment: @rogerherbert I don't think that's sarcasm; this isn't a trivial task, and if you have to ask where to start it might be beyond your current level.

Comment: @Cyber: there are a lot of complicated things in the world which have been implemented as python libraries. Diffing text files is one of those.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Beyond my current level ? For sure, but asking for something you already know would be a non-sense, wouldn't it ?

Comment: `grep -Fxvf File2.txt File1.txt`

Comment: Oh god! It worked! 
Thanks :)

Comment: You say you want to "highlight the differences" but then your example shows only printing lines that are unique to one file. Which do you want? Are you wanting a full diff-like output, or just a list of lines that are missing from one file or the other? It's not quite clear what you're really wanting to do.

Comment: Excuse my bad english, what I wanted was the second option "a list of lines that are missing from one file or the other?", I thought "difference" meant that in a scenario like mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort File1.txt File2.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: Nice, that works too :)

Comment: Elegant. However, can this line run on python? It looks like linux bash command.

Comment: @user781486: This should work with any shell that supports pipes.

Answer (score 11):

Python has a library specifically for doing exactly this: [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html). You can feed it the contents of two text files and it will return back differences between the two.

For an example, see http://pymotw.com/2/difflib/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I already messed with it, and it's giving minus and plus signs, not really what I'm looking for, I only need to output the difference without other stuff

Comment: I know how to do that thanks :) But there might be a much more straight-forward solution, maybe with shell commands

Answer (score 8):

I used this in python, is simple, but it works

```
>>> File1 = open("file1","r")
>>> File2 = open("file2","r")
>>> Dict1 = File1.readlines()
>>> Dict2 = File2.readlines()
>>> print Dict1
['AAAAA\n', 'BBBBB\n', 'CCCCC\n']
>>> print Dict2
['AAAAA\n', 'BBBBB\n']
>>> DF = [ x for x in Dict1 if x not in Dict2 ]
>>> print DF
['CCCCC\n']
>>> print DF[0]
CCCCC

>>> print DF[0].rstrip()
CCCCC
```